# Intellij Idea: Is it possible to set breakpoints in decompiled code?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm debugging an attached Java process, in which I need to set breakpoints in the compiled code. Is it possible to step and set breakpoints using Intellij's decompiler and debugger?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that.   Just set bp in decompled source in the editor.

Comment: When pausing the application, and inspecting the stack (showing the decompiled code), I can't actually navigate to any other parts of the code other than the currently opened file. I can't jump to any definitions of types or methods referenced in the displayed decompiled file.

Comment: You can step into the class/method in the debugger, if you have the library added as a module.